# Vue Template - Making any URLs found in returned text string to a link

Tags: vue.js, npm

I am working on a project that is Vue modular based (code used is: https://github.com/mishushakov/dialogflow-web-v2/blob/bc3ce7d7cf8e09a34b5fda431590bd48cc31f66b/src/App.vue)

Linking to the file I think need to make the change to, have been trying but I don't really know Vue at all and had not luck.

The returned message is plain text for example: this is a test message, please visit https://wwww.google.com

What I am trying to do, is from that text string, if a URL found is to create a link from that found URL

```
<RichComponent><RichBubble v-if="message.queryResult.fulfillmentText" :text="message.queryResult.fulfillmentText" /></RichComponent>
```

Is what the current code is that returns the data.

Is there a best way to achieve this? Is there a core function maybe?

I have tried to `npm install linkify` but cannot seem to get it working so maybe a direct approach would be better?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `linkifyjs` to convert links in a string into anchor tags. The `linkifyjs/lib/linkify-string.js` file [augments the `String` prototype with a `linkify()` method](https://github.com/Soapbox/linkifyjs/blob/95333da/src/linkify-string.js#L81).

```html
<template>
  <p v-html="msg.linkify()"></p>
</template>

<script>
import 'linkifyjs/lib/linkify-string' // side effect: creates String.prototype.linkify

export default {
  props: ['msg'],
}
</script>
```

It also [exports that method](https://github.com/Soapbox/linkifyjs/blob/95333da/src/linkify-string.js#L100) if you prefer an explicit call:

```html
<template>
  <p v-html="linkify(msg)"></p>
</template>

<script>
import linkify from 'linkifyjs/lib/linkify-string'

export default {
  props: ['msg'],
  methods: {
    linkify,
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Using linkifyjs in Vue]

Comment: Be aware! v-html can easily lead to XSS attacks!
https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-html